# how to make more reliable search in oracle database SQL-92 standard search query?

Tags: sql, database, select, oracle10g

this is my search query
Below Database table example(`Products` table)

```
    |productname|
    | LCD Assembly Apple iPhone 5 (Grade: PLUS)|
```

it searches for `LCD Assembly Apple iPhone 5 (Grade: PLUS)` value in `productname` column

Below search query return results

```
SELECT productname,id FROM products where LOWER(productname) LIKE LOWER('%iphone%lcd%');
```

But Below search query return **zero** results(**Should** returns record: `LCD Assembly Apple iPhone 5 (Grade: PLUS)` )

```
SELECT productname,id FROM products where LOWER(productname) LIKE LOWER('%apple%iphone%lcd%');
```

**When I run above query it should returns record which column has `LCD Assembly Apple iPhone 5 (Grade: PLUS)` value in `productname` column**

so how can I solve this issue ?

Anyone have solution for this ?
If you have doubt in my question please ask me I will instant reply

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the problem is - which rows do you tro to search and what is the final goal? Because for the productname you mentioned as example neither first nor second quuery would return anything. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9dcbaf412024c1691d2dffae4b85e251

Comment: order is important : `'%apple%iphone%lcd%'` not equals `'%lcd%apple%iphone%'`

Comment: @Dornaut I edited my question please check

Comment: No way to do that easily and fast. Relational databases were not designed for this purpose(Full text search). Either replicate your data into Elastic or use Oracle Text index.

Comment: You say that the query with condition `LIKE LOWER('%apple%iphone%lcd%')`  should return `LCD Assembly Apple iPhone 5 (Grade: PLUS)` . It never return that record because the condition searches for records with `apple` before `lcd`, but this record has `lcd` before `apple`.

Comment: If you want those results in any order you need to use "full text search". I don't know if it's included by default in the Oracle license. As a long shot option, you could use PostgreSQL that has a fairly good implementation (and it's free).

Comment: @TheImpaler thanks